# Is it possible to use chaquopy library in flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, chaquopy

I am currently developing mobile app in Flutter together with chaquopy library to run some python code in it, I wanted to try building my app also as a Chrome (web) app but it seems that there is some problem on chaquopy side as I get this error - Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method runPythonScript on channel chaquopy). Web app runs but python code isn't executed anywhere.

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method runPythonScript on channel chaquopy)
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 288:49  throw_
packages/flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 308:7                     _invokeMethod
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 45:50            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1661:54                                          runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 147:18                                    handleValue
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 784:44                                    handleValueCallback
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 813:13                                    _propagateToListeners
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 584:5                                     [_completeWithValue]
dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 657:7                                     callback
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 40:11                              _microtaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5                               _startMicrotaskLoop
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 177:15           <fn>
```

I have already tried flutter clean etc. without success. Mobile app is working no problem but web seems currently unsupported by chaquopy library maybe? Did anyone succesfully build a flutter web app using chaquopy?

Answer (score 1):

No chaquopy does not support the Web platform, actually it supports only android As it says on it's pub dev page.

[image]

I have searched for some alternative packages for your need, there's one [pocketpy](https://pub.dev/packages/pocketpy), it's lightweight Python interpreter for game engines, but i guess it can do your job too.